# No sound with HDA Intel PCH - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, hda-intel

I have recently dual booted my Samsung 300V5A - S0GIN laptop with ubuntu 18.04. I couldn't get audio over 3.5mm headphone jack. However, I have work USB headphones which works without a hitch.

I have tried a unmuting from alsa mixer, It worked initially but is not working now. I would really appreciate any help on this.